# Can I dynamically generate a WITH RESULT SETS clause for a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: r, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure where I execute an R script, and return a data frame as the output. The procedure queries a linked server, performs a variety of transformations on the result of the original query, and returns the resulting data frame.

Here are details about my environment:

```
Product: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit)
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.3 (9600)
Platform: NT x64
Version: 13.0.5216.0
```

The script in the stored procedure is as follows:

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R',
@script = N'
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

##store initial query as a data frame
goldInstrumentDF <- data.frame(InputDataSet)

##set load_ts as a timestamp
formattedDF <- transform(goldInstrumentDF, load_ts = ymd_hms(as.character(goldInstrumentDF$load_ts)))

##set all other column values as characters
i <- sapply(formattedDF, is.factor)
formattedDF[i] <- lapply(formattedDF[i], as.character)

##unpack json object
firstTransform <- formattedDF %>%
  mutate(event = map(event, ~ fromJSON(.) %>% as.data.frame())) %>%
  unnest(event)

##store load events in a data frame
loadEvents <- firstTransform[firstTransform$object.method == "IMM_Equipment_RePro_Load_Event", ]

##store equipment events in a data frame
equipmentEvents <- firstTransform[firstTransform$object.method != "IMM_Equipment_RePro_Load_Event", ]

##parse the initial characters from the non-standard data exchange format
equipmentSubstring <- equipmentEvents %>% mutate(object.object = substring(equipmentEvents$object.object, 19))

##remove the curly bracked from the end of the non-standard data exchange format
equipmentSubstring2 <- equipmentSubstring %>% mutate(object.object = gsub(''.$'', '''', equipmentSubstring$object.object))

##remove the single quotes from the non-standard data exchange format
equipmentSubstring3 <- equipmentSubstring2 %>% mutate(object.object = gsub("''", "", equipmentSubstring2$object.object))

##split the data from the non-standard data exchange format into a header and a value
namev<-function(x) {
  a<-strsplit(x,"=")
  setNames(sapply(a,''['',2), sapply(a,''['',1))
}

##turn each row into a named vector
secondTransform <- lapply(strsplit(equipmentSubstring3$object.object, ","), namev)

##find list of all column names
thirdTransform <- unique(unlist(sapply(secondTransform, names)))

##extract data from all rows for every column
fourthTransform <-do.call(rbind, lapply(secondTransform, ''['', thirdTransform))

##rejoin with original data
fifthTransform <-cbind(equipmentSubstring3[,-25], fourthTransform)

##remove exraneous columns
drops <- c(" error", "object.object", NA)
sixthTransform <- fifthTransform[ , !(names(fifthTransform) %in% drops)]

##output the data frame
OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(sixthTransform)',
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT * FROM openquery(KMhivehttp, ''select * from dmfwk_gold.instrumentapps_event;'');
```

Is there any way for me to dynamically define a WITH RESULTS SET clause based upon the data in my dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that as `WITH RESULTS SET` is part of the stored procedure execution. I guess you'd want to do that due to your `sixthTransform`, where you remove erroneous columns?

If that is the case (removal of columns), perhaps it would be better if you returned the erroneous columns, but had them assigned a "magic" value? That way you'd always get a deterministic resultset back.

Comment: The code that you see above is just part of a proof of concept. The reason that I want to dynamically output my results set is because I will eventually parameterize this stored procedure to accept a query for the input data in my script. After I unpack the JSON object, the datasets that I'm parsing will vary based on the query, hence my desire to dynamically return my results. Thanks for your assistance Niels.

Comment: Oh, I see - yeah - in that context it would make sense to change the `WITH RESULT SETS`. Thanks for the clarification!